# Setup JPackage installer that it will not override config files in the newer versions

Tags: java, gradle, jpackage

I'm using jpackage from Java 14, Here is the Jpackage chunk of my build.gradle :

```
runtime {

    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    modules = ['java.desktop', 'jdk.jfr', 'java.xml', 'jdk.unsupported', 'java.scripting', 
               'java.sql', 'java.logging', 'java.management', 'java.naming']

    launcher {
        noConsole = true
    }

    jpackage {
    
         installerName='CTG-Simulator'
         appVersion = '0.9.1'
         imageOptions += ['--icon', 'src/main/resources/images/simulator-icon.ico','--vendor', 'Trium']
   
        if(org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
            installerType = 'msi'
            installerOptions = ['--win-per-user-install', '--win-menu', '--win-shortcut']
        }
        if(org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().linux) {
            installerType = 'deb'
            installerOptions = ['--linux-deb-maintainer gerhard.aigner@gmail.com']
        }

    }
}

tasks.jpackageImage.doLast {
 println 'Copying : config file and data folder ...'
    copy {
        from "src/main/resources"
        include "config.properties","data/*"
        into "build/jpackage/$project.name"
    }
}
```

In **tasks.jpackageImage.doLast** I'm adding **config.properties** and the **data** directory to the installer so that will be automatically included in my install directory when executing the installer.
Is there any way to customize the installer so that it will not override those files on newer versions?